# get RMSE of forecast by Exponential Smoothing

Tags: r, time-series

In using R for Exponential Smoothing on time series, I am using [Average Yearly Temperatures in New Haven](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/datasets/nhtemp.csv) as an example.

The code uses year 1912 to 1960 as training data, and produces a forecast for the coming 11 years.

I want to compare the forecast with the actual of year 1961 to 1971, but there are 2 problems:

1. The “nht_1” to get the actual values returns some wrong numbers
2. An error pops when trying to get the RMSE:

   Error in order(y) : unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'

How can I have them corrected, and get the RMSE of the forecast values? Thank you.

(note: besides use the accuracy command from the forecast package. I want to try to get RMSE this way...)

```
df <- read.csv("D:\\Documents\\nhtemp.csv")

nht <- ts(df$value, 
          start = c(1912),
          end = c(1960),
          frequency = 1)

nht.hw1 <- HoltWinters(df$value, gamma = F); nht.hw1

library(forecast)

nht.forecast <- forecast(nht.hw1, h = 11)
nht.forecast

# I want to compare the forecast with the actual of year 1961 to 1971:
nht_1 <- ts(df$value, 
     start = c(1961),
     end = c(1971),
     frequency = 1)

nht_1
# returns wrong numbers: 49.9 52.3 49.4 51.1 49.4 47.9 49.8 50.9 49.3 51.9 50.8

# For getting its RMSE

library(caret)
postResample(nht_1, nht.forecast)
# Error in order(y) : unimplemented type 'list' in 'orderVector1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to check accuracy on forecast objects:

```
library(forecast)
data(woolyrnq) #data I will use, it is already a ts object
```

The `stats::window` function can be used to subset the `ts`

```
train <- window(woolyrnq, end = c(1984,4)) #a vector of two numbers, year and quarter since its quarterly ts
test <- window(woolyrnq, start = c(1985,1), end = c(1987, 4))
```

Estimate model:

```
nht.hw1 <- HoltWinters(train, gamma = FALSE)
```

Obtain forecasts:

```
nht.forecast <- forecast(nht.hw1, h = 12)
```

Check accuracy:

```
accuracy(nht.forecast, x = test)
#output
                     ME     RMSE      MAE       MPE     MAPE     MASE      ACF1 Theil's U
Training set  -69.69645 679.9740 554.6501 -1.877270 10.31036 1.136701 0.1882675        NA
Test set     -504.14620 809.8686 638.8314 -9.699182 11.78262 1.309222 0.1399736 0.9250198
```

If you want to use `caret`:

```
library(caret)
RMSE(pred = nht.forecast$mean, #just the mean and not the data frame with the CIs
     obs = test)
#output
809.8686
```

EDIT
Using data provided in question:

```
df <- read.csv("nhtemp.csv")
```

create a time series from all the data:

```
nht <- ts(df$value, 
          start = c(1912),
          end = c(1971),
          frequency = 1)
```

create train and test sets:

```
train <- window(nht, end = 1960) #just one number as end since its yearly data
test <- window(nht, start = 1961)
```

fit:

```
nht.hw1 <- HoltWinters(train, gamma = FALSE)
```

forecast

```
nht.forecast <- forecast(nht.hw1, h = 10)
```

evaluate

```
accuracy(nht.forecast, x = test)
                      ME      RMSE       MAE        MPE      MAPE      MASE        ACF1 Theil's U
Training set -0.25921398 1.7027155 1.3840629 -0.5616971 2.7249636 1.0462208 -0.05478676        NA
Test set     -0.04523057 0.5478937 0.4651413 -0.0981410 0.9080928 0.3516029  0.08720340 0.7664426
```

Comment: this is a fantastic answer and help! marvelous job, keep on the sharing, @missue!